# Divide column value by number of rows within a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Impala with fields: Campaign ID, Account, Start Date, End Date, Transaction Date and Revenue. There are multiple campaigns having same account and revenue values. I want to divide the revenue values between the campaigns that fall within the range [Transaction_Date, Transaction_Date + 36 months].
Sample Table:

```
    Campaign  | Account | Start Date | End Date | Trans. Date | Revenue
       1      |   1234  | 13-05-17   | 13-06-17 | 19-10-17    | 200
       2      |   1234  | 14-01-16   | 14-02-16 | 19-10-17    | 200
       2      |   5678  | 14-01-16   | 14-02-16 | 07-02-16    | 200
       3      |   2345  | 20-05-15   | 20-07-15 | 22-05-15    | 300
       4      |   1234  | 15-10-13   | 15-11-13 | 19-10-17    | 200
       4      |   5678  | 15-10-13   | 15-11-13 | 22-05-15    | 300
```

Here, the revenue for account 1234 should be split between campaigns 1 and 2, and not 4 since the transaction date falls 36 months after the campaign started. While the revenue for account 2345 should be split between campaigns 2 and 4.
So the result table should be as:

```
    Campaign  | Account | Start Date | End Date | Trans. Date | Revenue | Avg Revenue
       1      |   1234  | 13-05-17   | 13-06-17 | 19-10-17    | 200     | 100
       2      |   1234  | 14-01-16   | 14-02-16 | 19-10-17    | 200     | 100
       2      |   5678  | 14-01-16   | 14-02-16 | 07-02-16    | 200     | 200
       3      |   2345  | 20-05-15   | 20-07-15 | 22-05-15    | 300     | 150
       4      |   1234  | 15-10-13   | 15-11-13 | 19-10-17    | 200     | NULL
       4      |   2345  | 15-10-13   | 15-11-13 | 22-05-15    | 300     | 150
```

EDIT:
Essentially, I want to do the following:
1. For each row, get all rows for that account where the trans_date falls between the start date and start date + 3 years.
2. Divide the revenue in each of those rows by the number of rows.
I have tried to make this work using a partition, but I am not sure how to create one with a variable range based on the date values.
Hope this makes it clearer.
Thanks!

Comment: Which rdbms? What have you tried? Help us help you.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using Impala..
I've tried using a partition query, but I wasn't sure how to go about it for a varying date range..

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Oracle, the concept should be able to be adapted to Postgres..

```
drop table test;

create table test as
select 1 as Campaign, 1234 as Account, to_date('13-05-17', 'DD-MM-YY') as Start_Date, to_date('13-06-17', 'DD-MM-YY') as End_Date, to_date('19-10-17', 'DD-MM-YY') as Trans_Date, 200 as Revenue from dual union all
select 2 as Campaign, 1234 as Account, to_date('14-01-16', 'DD-MM-YY') as Start_Date, to_date('14-02-16', 'DD-MM-YY') as End_Date, to_date('19-10-17', 'DD-MM-YY') as Trans_Date, 200 as Revenue from dual union all
select 2 as Campaign, 5678 as Account, to_date('14-01-16', 'DD-MM-YY') as Start_Date, to_date('14-02-16', 'DD-MM-YY') as End_Date, to_date('07-02-16', 'DD-MM-YY') as Trans_Date, 200 as Revenue from dual union all
select 3 as Campaign, 2345 as Account, to_date('20-05-15', 'DD-MM-YY') as Start_Date, to_date('20-07-15', 'DD-MM-YY') as End_Date, to_date('22-05-15', 'DD-MM-YY') as Trans_Date, 300 as Revenue from dual union all
select 4 as Campaign, 1234 as Account, to_date('15-10-13', 'DD-MM-YY') as Start_Date, to_date('15-11-13', 'DD-MM-YY') as End_Date, to_date('19-10-17', 'DD-MM-YY') as Trans_Date, 200 as Revenue from dual union all
select 4 as Campaign, 2345 as Account, to_date('15-10-13', 'DD-MM-YY') as Start_Date, to_date('15-11-13', 'DD-MM-YY') as End_Date, to_date('22-05-15', 'DD-MM-YY') as Trans_Date, 300 as Revenue from dual 
;

select
   a.*
  ,case when Start_Date + (365 * 3) > Trans_Date then Revenue else null end / count(case when Start_Date + (365 * 3) > Trans_Date then 1 else null end) over (partition by account) as Avg_Revenue
from test a
order by Campaign, Account
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. How is this different from using a where clause as  

`select a.*, revenue/count(campaign) over (partition by account) as avg_revenue from test a` ?

Comment: A where clause would exclude the fifth row in your sample data from the results. My method includes it but with null Avg Revenue.

Comment: Oh okay.. Thanks. Let me check the results and will let you know.

EDIT: Just realized I didn't add the complete query in the previous comment. Just for the record, it was:  

`select a.*, revenue/count(campaign) over (partition by account) as avg_revenue from test a where start_date + (365 * 3) > trans_date`